# Menu will push the Footer away

Tags: css, menu, styles, footer, effect

I've a problem with my Dropdown menu. When you hover it, it will push the Footer away, and it will create a freaky effect that you can scroll the whole page. (This is only when the dropdown reach the footer)
I have tried lots of things like max-height etc, but it wont work.

Website:
{fixed}

If you hover the 'Zippo' menu item, the freaky things will come.

How can i fix this?

Thanks!
Wouter0100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your dropdown menu position as absolute :

```
#nav li ul {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: 25px;
   z-index: 99; /* edited */
}
```

Comment: I just tried it in live on your website and it worked. What's wrong exactly ?

Comment: http://static.afbeeldinguploaden.nl/1209/18054/M8f.png its still over the footer, is there a way to put the items that are over the footer on a new line? like:

Answer (score 1):

Change the following class from :

```
#nav li ul {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
display: none;
}
```

to

```
#nav li ul {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: The css is on line 331, if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Footer drop down because of the height of the menu nav height

to over come this you need to pull menu out of the normal Dom by position it

```
#menu {position: relative;}
#nav {z-index: 100;position: absolute; }
```